# how to add book mark,page curl and menu navigation

Tags: android

I am trying to make ebook and need to implement popup dictionary, page curl and from menu we can navigate to the chapters directly, pdf is static which is from asserts folder.
https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer, I am using this library

Comment: Show what you already did.

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        PDFView pdfView= (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        pdfView.fromAsset("sample1.pdf").enableSwipe(true).swipeHorizontal(true).enableDoubletap(true).defaultPage(0).load();
        pdfView.useBestQuality(true);
        pdfView.fitToWidth();

    }
}

Comment: This is the code for loading the pdf from asserts folder but after that , what and how , i dont know please help me